# Enumerating 10-high hands and lower within 14 of 52 cards

Tags: combinatorics

Standard deck of cards - 13 numbers (or ranks) and 4 suits (spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs.). The goal is to define the number of 10-high hands or lower when dealt 14 of 52 card deck.

10-high hand is the hand containing five cards of different Ranks, e.g. 10,9,7,4,2 where the highest rank is 10 or lower and it does not consist of the cards of the same suit, i.e. cards do not form "flush". To qualify, such hand cannot be the "straight" either (5 consecutive ranks, i.e. 34567). –

Straights and flushes do not count as low hands.

I am just trying to find a proper approach and verify it on one of the examples.

First, I split high and low cards by following partitions (H/L):

9/5, 8/6, 7/7, 6/8, 5/9, 4/10, 3/11, 2/12, 1/13, 0/14.

Then I examined each partition type one by one:

9/5:

- C(16,9)x[C(9,5)x4^5-4-5]

I am deducting 4 flushes, one of each suit, and 5 straights (with smallest cards: 2,3,4,5,6)

Question 1: Should I deduct more than 4 flushes? considering they can be completed with several 5-spades combinations.

Question 2: Should my straights be multiplied by the suits each card would take and subtract the all the same suit combs( for not to over count flushes?)

8/6:

- C(16,8)xC(9,6)x4^6 
  for a non-paired 6-card low hands and
- C(16,8)xC(9,1)xC(4,2)xC(8,4)x4^4
  for a paired 6-card low hands.

And how shall I approach deducting straights and flushes here, please?

Comment: Please define "high hands" and "low hands" for non-poker players.

Comment: in order a low hand to qualify, one must come up with a 5-card combination without a flush, straight, pair or better, and none of the cards must be higher than 10. Aces are only high cards. High hands do not have any restrictions.

Comment: Please define "flush", "straight" and "better" for non-poker players.

Comment: Sorry about it. Flush - 5 cards of the same suit. Straight - 5 consecutive cards but not of the same suit. e.g. (2,3,4,5,6 or 6,7,8,9,10).

Comment: Suit? Is that the shape on the card? Are there $4$ possible suits and $13$ possible numbers? What do you mean by "$10$-high hands or lower"? Your question is phrased in a very poor manner IMO. Keep in mind that this is a math-oriented site. You should specify all the relevant numerical details as if they have nothing to do with poker, and try to refrain from using poker terminology (which requires poker knowledge).

Comment: I am sorry about unclear description. Edited the text to incorporate your requests, thanks.